# Java Console (from Configure Java) not outputting any of my System.out.println

Tags: java, console, applet

I'm working on a Java applet, while the System.out.println works in my main method in Eclipse (it shows up in the console), after I call the applet, any System.out.println is not showing either in my IDE (Eclipse)'s console or Java console when I access my web application.

How may I see my System.out.println from the Java Applet?

Comment: What do you mean by call the applet?

Comment: In my .jsp I have a <applet>...</applet>